# Jquery: Exclude a contained element

Tags: jquery-selectors, element

Chouette

I'd like to mouseoverize the div but not the img

```
$('div').mouseover(go_truc);
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the `mouseenter` event, but do nothing `if ($(e.target).is('img'))`.

Then, handle the `<img>` element's `mouseenter` event, and undo the effect.

Comment: Putting a return(false) at the end of the img.mouseover fonction ?
Is it the best solution ?

Answer (score 0):

With

```
function do_trucs() {
  ...
}

function do_machins() {
  ...
  return (false);
}

$('div').mouseover(do_trucs);
$('div img').mouseover(do_machins);
```

It's working, but is it the simplest/best solution ?

(Anyway I need to handle the img.mouseover for other purpose)